# How to turn off printing the commands just executed

Tags: gdb

I am not sure how to call it, basically I have such user defined command:

```
define dump_stack

    set $i = stackTop
    while $i >= 0
        if stackPtr[1]->bytes == 0
            printf "0x%x\n", stackPtr[$i] 
        else
            printf "0x%x:%s\n", stackPtr[$i], stackPtr[$i]->bytes
        end
        set $i = $i - 1 
    end 
end
```

When I call this command inside gdb, I see this:

```
(gdb) dump_stack 
+dump_stack 
++set $i = stackTop
++while $i >= 0
+++if stackPtr[1]->bytes == 0
++++printf "0x%x\n", stackPtr[$i]
0x55756f40
+++set $i = $i - 1
+++if stackPtr[1]->bytes == 0
++++printf "0x%x\n", stackPtr[$i]
0x5576ba50
+++set $i = $i - 1
+++if stackPtr[1]->bytes == 0
++++printf "0x%x\n", stackPtr[$i]
0x5576ac70
+++set $i = $i - 1
+++if stackPtr[1]->bytes == 0
++++printf "0x%x\n", stackPtr[$i]
0x5576ac10
+++set $i = $i - 1
```

You can see all those lines starting with "+" are very noisy.

What is the command to turn it off so that, for the above, I only see:

```
0x55756f40
0x5576ba50
0x5576ac70
0x5576ac10
```

Thanks!

[**UPDATE**] Find the answer: set trace-commands off

Comment: Will "+" characters appear if invoke gdb with `-n` option?